# Cannot connect to a database with mysqli

Tags: php, html, database, connection

I try to connect with the database but I'm getting the following error:

**Error Image:**
[image: Error when running]

**My code to connect to the database:**

[image]

Comment: care to post code instead of an "image of"? and what's line 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysqli`.
2. check if database named `web2_db` exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'web2_db');
// btw protect your db with a password
if ($conn->connect_errno != 0)
    die($errormsg);
```